# Backbiting and cursing family

Tags: sin, tawba, backbiting

I was angry at my family for some personal stuff going on and I talked bad about them with someone else. They don’t know but I said some horrible stuff like how they can die and go to hell. I apologized to them for being rude that day but I still feel bad for the other things I said behind their back. How can I repent for this

Comment: Ask Allah for forgiveness and try to avoid what you did in the future. If you want you can do Salat al-Tawbah. And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

That which has happened has happened. The good part is that you have apologized for your doing. This feeling of being still disturbed about it is not bad. It has a lesson for you, in particular, and for us all, in general. Showing mercy even in times of anger is a virtue.

Allah says in the Quran, "Obey Allah and the Messenger, so you may be shown mercy. And hasten towards forgiveness from your Lord and a Paradise as vast as the heavens and the earth, prepared for those mindful ˹of Allah˺. ˹They are˺ those who donate in prosperity and adversity, **control their anger and pardon others**. And **Allah loves the good-doers**. ˹They are˺ those who, **upon committing an evil deed or wronging themselves, remember Allah and seek forgiveness and do not knowingly persist in sin**—and who forgives sins except Allah?   [[3:132-235]](https://quran.com/3/132-135)

Answer (score 0):

Talking badly about a family with someone else is definitely wrong. However, the good part is that you realized your mistake.

You know... backbiting is one of the worst sins that a person can make. It comes under major sins of Islam.

Allah says in the Qur'an:

“O you who have believed, avoid much [negative] assumption. Indeed, some assumption is sin. And do not spy or backbite each other. Would one of you like to eat the flesh of his brother when dead? You would detest it. And fear Allah; indeed, Allah is Accepting of repentance and Merciful.”

- Surah Al Hujurat Ayah 12

Make Dua sincerely and ask forgiveness from Allah, and focused on your future. Make a mindset that never to repeat such sinful acts, not only related to family but also avoid talking bad about anyone in this world.

Make Allah forgive our sins and save us from whispers of shaitan, Aameen.

Answer (score 0):

Apologize to them and repent to Allah by sincerely asking him for forgiveness and then you will be forgiven inshallah. Allah loves to forgive and is always waiting for us to ask him for forgiveness. “Say: “  “O My servants who have exceeded the limits against their souls! Do not lose hope in Allah’s mercy, for Allah certainly forgives all sins. He is indeed the All-Forgiving, Most Merciful.” [Surah Zumar verse 53]. Keep in mind that you also are required to apologize to your family and ask them for forgiveness as well